# crystal reports if statements with multiple tables

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

My report that pulls codes from two different tables for an EEO form. Some employees are assigned "Jobs" and others are assigned "Positions" - so they are stored in different tables.

The EEO Code in the Jobs table is `eeo_sub_code` which consists of digits 2 through 9. The EEO Code in the Positions Table is `position_group_code` which consits of  EEO2 through EEO9. I want both of these to display as EEO2 through EEO9.

`jobs.eeo_sub_code` and `positions.position_group_code` bot essentially contain EEO codes, so I'd like to merge them into a single column.

My codes so far only displays the `jobs.eeo_sub_code` condition. How can I get the desired behavior?

```
if {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '2' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO2' then 'EEO2' 
else if {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '3' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO3' then 'EEO3' 
else if {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '4' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO4' then 'EEO4' 
else if {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '5' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO5' then 'EEO5' 
else if {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '6' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO6' then 'EEO6' 
else if {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '7' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO7' then 'EEO7' 
else if {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '8' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO8' then 'EEO8' 
else if {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '9' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO9' then 'EEO9'
```

Comment: What you have done with table links, and what is the primary key or common colomn you have between these tables?

Answer (score 1):

Check the link between your tables. If properly linked, you cab try the following formula:

```
IF {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '2' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO2'
  THEN 'EEO2' 
ELSE IF  {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '3' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO3' 
  THEN 'EEO3'
ELSE IF  {jobs.eeo_sub_code} = '4' OR {positions.position_group_code} = 'EEO4' 
  THEN 'EEO4'

//...And so forth
```